# Browse Address Bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

If I copy the URL while in login mode and then after logout I paste it in the address bar and press enter it shows the page.

Is there any possible way to know the URL from the address bar of browser?

Comment: I'm sorry, and I'm not trying to be rude, but I am unable to comprehend the meaning of the question as a result of the poor quality of English. Is there any way you could re-phrase the question so that we might understand it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mean `location.href` ? Please elaborate on what you are doing. For example visit the [help] to see how to ask questions. I have edited your question - guessing what you are asking. I have tried to guess what you mean. You can use `location.replace(url)` to keep the previous page out of history and also try to keep the pages out of cache.

Comment: You don't need to know how the user got there. You should just check whether the session variable that says he's logged in is set.

Comment: @mplungjan I think what he's saying is that he logs out of his application, then manually enters the URL of one of the internal pages, and it lets him access it even though he's not logged in.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is what I changed the question to reflect

Comment: Well if you still can see the page you actually didn't log out..

Comment: @mplungjan and Barmar thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The address bar is irrelevant, the same thing could happen if there's another web page with a link to the URL.

All the pages of your application need to check whether the user is logged in before they display anything. Logging in should set a session variable, and every page should check that. In my example code below, it redirects to the login page if they're not logged in.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

The logout page should do `unset($_SESSION['username'])`.

Comment: However if the page is still in cache, it will still show the page.

Comment: Not much you can do about that. He can also take a screenshot of the page and see it forever.

Comment: If course. However there are methods (new windows, session as you mention, location.replace) that can help somewhat

Answer (score 1):

While login or logout, you are definitely accessing the session variables.
To solve this problem. simply place a check on every url of your application whether the session variable is set or not.

If set then the provide the data from your application. If not redirect the request to your login page.
Also, when user manually clicks logout be sure to clear/unset all session variables of user session.
I hope it will work